# Exclude specific page from sitemap.xml generation

Tags: magento

I was wondering if there is a method to exclude one specific CMS page from being added / included in the sitemap generation of Magento.

Some expert advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example by overriding `Mage_Sitemap_Model_Resource_Cms_Page::getCollection` like this:

```
public function getCollection($storeId)
{
    $pages = array();

    $select = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->select()
        ->from(array('main_table' => $this->getMainTable()), array($this->getIdFieldName(), 'identifier AS url'))
        ->join(
            array('store_table' => $this->getTable('cms/page_store')),
            'main_table.page_id=store_table.page_id',
            array()
        )
        // --- exclude single CMS page "enable-cookies"
        ->where('main_table.identifier<>"enable-cookies"')
        // --- exclude multiple CMS pages "home", "enable-cookies"
        // ->where('main_table.identifier NOT IN (?)', array('home', 'enable-cookies')) 
        // ---
        ->where('main_table.is_active=1')
        ->where('store_table.store_id IN(?)', array(0, $storeId));
    $query = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->query($select);
    while ($row = $query->fetch()) {
        if ($row['url'] == Mage_Cms_Model_Page::NOROUTE_PAGE_ID) {
            continue;
        }
        $page = $this->_prepareObject($row);
        $pages[$page->getId()] = $page;
    }

    return $pages;
}
```

In case you don't know how to override a Magento model class yet, have a look at Alan Storm's article [Magento for Developers: Part 1 - Introduction to Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento), especially sections "Models" and "Class overrides".

Comment: Thank you for the heads up Mr. Thelen. This seeem a rather complicated solution. How can I apply this if I want to exclude my main homepage from being included in the sitemap generation. The name itself would be "home". Your expert advice would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Well, in the example above, I excluded the CMS page "enable-cookies" as an example, so you only need to replace `"enable-cookies"` by `"home"`.

Comment: @JürgenThelen We are trying to exclude multiple pages and products from the sitemap, about 10 products and pages.  Do you know if we can simply chain multiple `->where('main_table.identifier<>"enable-cookies"')` together, each with the page or product and have this method work, or is this a 1 page exclude kind of thing?  Appreciate any insight I am new to Magento.  I should ask if this will even work for a Product instead of a CMS Page too

Comment: @jasondavis: Updated my answer with a sample `where` clause that shows how to exclude multiple CMS pages at once. Excluding products works a bit differently, but explaining it would be off-topic within this post, I guess. Please just post a separate question about excluding products from sitemaps. I'm sure, it'll be answered.